# Switch between G++ version to support C++11

Tags: c++, g++

I have installed 4.7 version of c++ which does not support c++11. So I followed [This](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/) and installed new version which also 4.7. Now I am confused how I switch newely installed g++.

When I enter `ls -lh /usr/bin/g++*` I get this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Aug 23 08:54 /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 516K Apr 15 17:42 /usr/bin/g++-4.7
```

Both are same but How can I switch to newer?

Comment: That page already explains how to do it. `sudo update-alternatives --config g++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc 4.7 *does* support C++11, if you run it with the `-std=c++11` option. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, i was not knowing it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way your package installer would have let you have two separate installations of g++ 4.7. The page you linked states that you'd end up with both 4.6 and 4.7, not two versions 4.7.

If you had different g++ version, you could select which one gets used by the `g++` command using `update-alternatives --config g++`, however running `g++-4.7` will always get you the 4.7 version.

Also note that 4.7 does support some C++11 features (use -std=c++11), but not all of them. [This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) lists the status of the implementation.